# How to pass the variable from a ViewController Class to other Struct?

Tags: swift, class, struct, communication

I have no idea how to pass the data from the class to another struct. This is my ViewController.swift file. And I have another file called Meme.swift which is used to save the struct. I tried to put the struct in ViewController.swift file as well as Meme.swift file but I cannot access the value like `topTextField.text` and `lowTextField.text` and use them in the struct. Can anyone help me with this?
ViewController:
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraButton: UIBarButtonItem!

```
@IBOutlet weak var bottomTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var topTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var imagePickerView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var actionButton: UIBarButtonItem!
let bottomTextFieldDelegate = BottomTextFieldDelegate()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    topTextField.text = "TOP"
    bottomTextField.text = "BOTTOM"
    topTextField.delegate = self
    bottomTextField.delegate = self.bottomTextFieldDelegate

}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    topTextField.text = ""
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    actionButton.isEnabled = true
    return true
}

@IBAction func shareAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let image = generateMemedImage()
    let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image as Any], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    controller.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: UIActivityType?, completed:Bool, returnedItems:[Any]?, error: Error?) in

        if !completed {
            debugPrint("cancelled")
            return
        }else{
            self.save()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    cameraButton.isEnabled = UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)
    configureTextField(textField: topTextField)
    configureTextField(textField: bottomTextField)
    topTextField.textAlignment = .center
    bottomTextField.textAlignment = .center
    subscribeToKeyboardNotifications()
    actionButton.isEnabled = false

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications()
}

func configureTextField(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.defaultTextAttributes = memeTextAttributes
}


func save() -> Meme {
    // Create the meme
    let memedImage = generateMemedImage()
    let meme = Meme(topText: topTextField.text!, bottomText: bottomTextField.text!, originalImage: imageView.image!, memedImage: memedImage)

    return meme
}

func generateMemedImage() -> UIImage {

    // TODO: Hide toolbar and navbar
    navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

    // Render view to an image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let memedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // TODO: Show toolbar and navbar
    navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

    return memedImage
}


func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {

    view.frame.origin.y = 0 - getKeyboardHeight(notification)
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification:Notification) {

    view.frame.origin.y = 0 

}

func getKeyboardHeight(_ notification:Notification) -> CGFloat { //getting the height of keyboard and use it for func keyboardWillShow to relocate
    //the keyboard using keyboardWillShow function

    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue // of CGRect
    return keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
}

func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() { //setting up the obeserver to be notified when keyboard is shown or not, then execute keyboardWillShow function

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications() { //unsubscribe the notification

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
//setting the arributes of the text
let memeTextAttributes:[String:Any] = [
    NSStrokeColorAttributeName: UIColor.black,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: 3,]


@IBAction func pickAnImageFromAlbum(_ sender: Any) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


@IBAction func pickAnImageFromCamera(_ sender: Any) {

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imagePickerView.image = image
        imagePickerView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController){
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

BottomFieldDelegate:

import Foundation
import UIKit

class BottomTextFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.text = ""
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let viewController = ViewController()
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    viewController.view.endEditing(true)
    let actionButton = viewController.actionButton
    actionButton?.isEnabled = true
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: Does it need to be a struct? Is NSObject not okay?

Comment: it needs to be a struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First u need to move this function like save() and generateMemedImage() into your ViewController class and then you can access topTextField.text and lowTextField.text

Modify your struct like below, and do not put nsobject in struct

```
struct Meme {
    var topText: String
    var bottomText: String
    var memedImage: UIImage
    var originalImage: UIImage

    init(topText: String, bottomText: String, originalImage: UIImage, memedImage: UIImage) {
        self.topText = topText
        self.bottomText = bottomText
        self.originalImage = originalImage
        self.memedImage = memedImage
    }
}
```

Remove save() from Meme struct and put that code in your Viewcontroller file.
Modify your function which return Meme struct object.

```
func save() -> Meme {
        // Create the meme
        let meme = Meme(topText: topTextField.text!, bottomText: bottomTextField.text!, originalImage: imageView.image!, memedImage: memedImage)
        return meme   
}
```

And you can store in Array like below.

```
let array:[Meme] = []
array.append(save())
```

Comment: I tried to put this into ViewController.swift file to check whether it will work but still it doesn't get the value that I want

Comment: @AndyKwok now u can try this, I edited my answer, forgot to modify you struct

Comment: It shows an error and says intance member 'topTextField' cannot be used on type 'ViewController' on the line initialising the meme.

Comment: @AndyKwok can you update viewController Class in your question, and show how's you initialized?

Comment: @AndyKwok, ooh man i already told you, you need to remove save function from your `Meme struct` and put that code into viewController file.

Comment: @AndyKwok, suggestion for you keep model class(Like Meme) file separate, do not put it together. keep your code clean.

Comment: @AndyKwok if it is helpful for you, then accept answer, so other people can directly go through this

Comment: **Never** suggest / use optional properties if they are initialized in an `init` method with non-optional parameters. Don't do that. It's very bad habit. Remove the question marks. The strong type system of Swift encourages to  avoid optionals as much as possible. Non-optional types can never crash,

Comment: No, neither exclamation marks. **Remove** them. Maybe you will be surprised but  you won't get a compiler error ;-).

Comment: @vadian the compiler throws an error when i remove the exclamation marks in the save() function.

Comment: @Hitesh I don't know why it crashes when i press return in the bottomTextField when it is empty. it says fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. but it works perfectly fine when I do the same in the topTextField

Comment: should i ask a new question or you can help me with it?

Comment: If the values can be optional declare them as optional by adding `?` at the end of the property types **and** the parameter types in the `init` method. Then remove all exclamation marks in the `save()` method.

Comment: @AndyKwok you need to make optional for need a parameter type like  `var topText: String?`